# Is there anyway for mongodb to make a new db automatically every month?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, discord.js

I have a db that collects stats for a game me and some friends play, and those stats reset every 31 days. What I am trying to figure out is if there is anyway for mongodb to make monthly databases. So every month a new Db with the same config is made, just with empty values and will be populated during the month.

Comment: MongoDB does not have a built-in task scheduler. You'll need to use a third-party scheduler (e.g., [`crontab`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) on Linux) to run Mongo commands. What environment are you using?

Comment: @Adam Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Windows 10, I recommend using Windows Task Scheduler to run a script to duplicate a template database at the beginning of every month.

Before you get into the script that will duplicate a database, you'll need to create a template database that will serve as the source for each copy. In this example I'll simply call the template database `stats-template`. Create it, and set it up however you need to.

Now you need the batch script:

```
@echo off

set year=%date:~-4%
set month=%date:~4,2%

set newdb=stats-%year%-%month%

mongodump --db stats-template
mongorestore --db %newdb% dump/stats-template

rmdir /s /q dump
```

This will create a dump (BSON data) of the `stats-template` database and then restore that data to a new database named `stats-[year]-[month]` (e.g., `stats-2019-03`). It also deletes the dump after the restore.

Now you need to create the task that will run this script once a month.

1. Open Task Scheduler
2. Click "Create Task..." (right side panel)
3. Name your task
4. Go to the Triggers tab and click "New"

   - Begin the task "On a schedule"
   - Select "Monthly"
   - Choose a good initial start time
   - Months: all
   - Days: 1
5. Go to the Actions tab and click "New"

   - Action: "Start a program"
   - Browse for the batch script from above
6. Click "OK" to create the task

Now you'll get a fresh database based on the template database on the first day of every month.

Answer (score -1):

You can add field with ttl index to every document in you collections. Mongodb will automatically delete those documents, when time is elapsed. [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/?searchProperty=current&query=create%20)